# Какие типичные задачи работы с базой данных решаются с помощью курсоров?

Tags: sql, база-данных, курсор

Курсор, как я понял - это некоторый аналог итератора в языках программирования. Это, также - указатель на одну строку, в наборе строк.

Те проекты, на которых я работал не пользовались функционалом курсора - ORM дёргало строки, и back-end их как-то обрабатывал.
Как я понял, при использовании курсора, когда дергается какой-то набор строк происходит блокировка - дополнительный минус при использовании в высоконагруженных проектах.

**Вопрос:** Какие типичные задачи (и на каком типичном стэке) обычно решают с помощью курсоров в коммерческих проектах?

Comment: Типичная задача - получение списка в курсоре (например, список имён таблиц) и итерация по нему динамическим SQL.

Comment: @Akina - получить список таблиц `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM postgres.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_schema = public` -я как-то без курсоров справлялся

Comment: Ну теперь представь, что в каждую таблицу, имя которой соответствует заданному шаблону, нужно добавить поле `created_at`... справься-ка без курсора. Ну или элементарно по шаблону имён таблиц вернуть те, у которых есть поле с заданным именем, а в нём - заданное значение. Ну то есть типичная задача - это когда надо в решении совместить работу и с данными, и с метаданными. Впрочем, наверное, существование такой задачи - индикатор неудачной архитектуры, но мало ли что притащится из прошлого..

Comment: @Akina вы знаете, похоже вы правы.